# Querying data from Microsoft SQL Server using GraphQL in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, sql-server, graphql-js

I have a node app (using express) that I built which can query my MS SQL server via the mssql npm package. I want to be able to use something like the express-graphql package to handle those queries. I have done this before with a Mongo DB and mongoose but I am having difficulty fitting these things together now. Does anyone know where I might find a tutorial ? I googled around and everything seemed to be for different SQL dbs. Alternatively, is there a better package I should be using?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to do this? Im trying to build a node.js server for microsoft SQL . How do I do it?

Comment: I cannot find a way to contact you @SonOfNye.  Did you ever solve this (using GraphQL in Node to connect to Microsoft SQL Server ?  Please contact me allard@oceanpark.com.